# Modelling influxdb data into tags and fields

Tags: influxdb, influxql

**TL;DR**
How to model data into fields vs tags incase you want to perform both group by and count(distinct())

So currently this is my influxdb data model:

```
api_requests (database)
   - requests_stats (measurement)
        - api_path (tag)
        - app_version (tag)
        - host (tag)
        - platform (tag) 

        - account_id (field)
        - user_id (field)
        - function_name (field)
        - network (field)
        - network_type (field)
        - time_to_execute (field)
```

So now I want to find out the number of distinct accounts (active accounts).
So I can run the following query:

```
SELECT count(distinct("account_id")) AS "active_accounts"
FROM "api_requests"."autogen"."requests_stats"
```

This works fine as account id is a field.

Now suppose I want to perform a group by operation on account_id, for example to find the number of requests received per account:

```
SELECT count("function_name") AS "request_count" 
FROM "api_requests"."autogen"."requests_stats"
GROUP BY "account_id"
```

I cannot do this as group by is recommended on tags.

How would one manage this kind of scenerio?

One of the solution is to store the value in both field and value but that would be data redundancy.

The other and the most optimal way would be for count(distinct()) to work on tags. Is this possible? This was actually a feature request in their github repo.

Or can something be done about the data model to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tag` for `account_id`. Instead of count query:

```
SELECT count(distinct("account_id")) AS "active_accounts"
FROM "api_requests"."autogen"."requests_stats"
```

use query, which will calculate exact [tag value cardinality](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/spec/#show-tag-values-cardinality):

```
SHOW TAG VALUES EXACT CARDINALITY WITH KEY = "account_id"
```

This will work only for your use case, because you don't want to use any additional (time, tag) filter in your distinct count query.

Comment: Is this part of the query language? I would like to create a dashboard in chronograf and add a widget inside the dashboard by incorporating this query.

Comment: Sure, there is already link to query language spec in my answer.

Comment: Ok I see an issue too related to the same filed by paul dix in year 2016 (https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/7195)

Comment: Ok so i tried out the following query (for demo purposes): `SHOW TAG VALUES CARDINALITY ON "api_requests" FROM "requests_stats" WITH KEY = "api_path"`.
This query yields a number 281 which is accurate. But this information is displayed only via the table widget and not single stat widget. Infact it displays NaN in the single stat widget. Would this be a bug in chronograf or is this the way its designed? Nonetheless your solution works so will be accepting it as the answer.

Comment: `SELECT count()` returns timeseries, but `SHOW TAG VALUES CARDINALITY` returns only single value. That can be a problem for singlestat widget.

Comment: Ahhhh that perfectly makes sense now. Lovely!

Comment: Ok so i went through their docs and found that we can indeed filter by time if we have tsi enabled. So i converted from tsm to tsi using `influx_inspect buildtsi -datadir your_data_dir -waldir your_wal_dir`. Although I still wasn't able to filter based on time. I checked their issues and found someone reporting the same (https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/9744).